# read the remote xml file in android

Tags: android, xml

I have a xml file in remote place.I want to use that xml file in my android project.can anyone give me a example code for this.I am using android 2.2.

P.S : I can access the local xml file which is in /res folder.
I don't know anything about xPath.

Comment: Something interesting... If you want to set it as layout in your activity then I think You can't..

Comment: thats just a xml file contains some  raw data.Here am not taking about layout/manifest xml.

Comment: Then you can use it by valid xml parser..

Comment: well i have used document builder and doc builder factory for accessing the content of the xml..My problem is how to retrieve the xml file which is in remote place.I have use HTTPUrlConnection but it is giving runtime error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
try {
            //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
            //this is the file to be downloaded
            URL url = new URL("http://IP/Downloads/data.xml");

            //create the new connection
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



            //and connect!
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file
            //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
            //sd card.
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
            //which we want to save the file as.
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"data.xml");

            //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
            progressDialog.setMax(totalSize);

            //variable to store total downloaded bytes
            int downloadedSize = 0;

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;

            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();
            //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try this code for downloading your xml file and check this tutorial for reading xml http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Comment: instead of saving xml in my sd card am using that dynamically for my search query.ty fr the link

Comment: Couldnt get u ..?? what do u mean by that  **dynamically for my search query.**

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set layout or drawable or style by remote xml , you can't.

Comment: No.i just want to use the xml data for some other purpose.not to set layout

Comment: Ok, then use http connection to get that xml in response, and parse it.

Comment: exactly...there only i have a problem.
        URL url = new URL("http://www.something.com/vishnu.xml");
urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();                 
                     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

Comment: If you are developing on Android 2.2 or later, you can take advantage of the javax.xml.xpath's functionality (introduced in API level 8).

Comment: ty...got the answer...Used SAXParser

Answer (score 0):

Better way to read it in String and do whatever you want to do with it.

public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) 
{
    String xml = null;

```
try 
{
    //default http client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    System.out.println("URL IN PARSER:==="+url+"====");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    HttpEntity httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);   // I have changed it... because ï»¿ occur while downloading..

    Log.d("response", xml);
} 
catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}


return xml;
```

}